# how to append in pl/sql

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am currently stuck on the following question:

Create a procedure which rewards an employee by appending an asterisk in the STARS column for every 100 euro of the employees salary

a.  Accept the employee id as input

b.  Initialize variable to contain string of stars

c.  Append asterisk to string for every 100 euro of salary e.g. salary 800, 8 asterisk's

d.  Update STARS column with string of asterisk's

e.  Test for employee with no salary and employee with salary

I have most of it done, but the part that gets me is part C, appending to a string.
I'm not looking for the answer for the whole question, just how to append.

Comment: Take a look at [RPAD](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions140.htm). Heck, the Oracle doc even uses a salary asterisk example :)

Comment: Thanks, Glenn and Aspirant. Question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Glenn suggested use RPAD functionality

for including `'*'` for every 100 euros assuming that your salary is in Euros

```
ltrim(rpad(' ',floor(salary/100)+1,'*'))
```

`ltrim` for just removing the space at the end of string after padding